# How to decompress gzip stream

Tags: c++, compression, gzip

I would like to send data over a network which is gzip compressed. The data is sent in chunks from a C# server which compresses it using a stream compressor before it sends. I would like the C++ client to be able to decompress the data as it comes in and write it to a file. I have looked alot over the internet but have not come up with a good solution as of now. Methods I have found of doing this don't seem to decompress it as a stream but rather as an entire char array, which is an issue because of the amount of memory the data takes up.

Comment: The [zlib](https://zlib.net/) library can decompress a gzip stream in chunks.  Simply push a chunk of compressed data into the library, get a decompressed chunk out, and write that to your file. Repeat until finished

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [zlib](https://zlib.net/) is for. It is a C library that supports decompressing whatever size chunks at a time you like, delivering as much uncompressed data as can be extracted so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I would launch `gzip` as a subprocess, fed by its standard input, and you read from its standard output the decompressed stream.

You need to either redirect the source stream to `gzip`'s `stdin`, or to pump it "manually" from your program.

How you launch a subprocess and hook its standard streams is usually at least partially platform-dependent, so we'll need details for a more detailled answer.

For example, if you use C++ on Windows or on Linux, "piping" data to a subprocess is a bit different, and it's even more different if you use a framework like Qt.